# Get SIM ICC Id from command line on Windows 11

Tags: command-line, windows-11, sim

On Windows 10 the command below works perfectly:

```
netsh mbn show read interface = *
```

This command then displays the details of the currently present SIM card in the tablets; State, Emergency mode (on or off), Subscriber ID, SIM ICC Id and Number of telephone numbers.

For the purposes of this question, assume there is always ever just 1 SIM card present and never more - I am not sure if multiple SIM cards being installed would result in all SIM's details being listed.

We specifically need to just know the SIM ICC Id.

The above command was tested on multiple Lenovo D330 and Lenovo Duet i3 Windows 10 tablets and it works flawlessly - with a bit of additional parameters the ICC Id can be extracted automatically, which is what we need to do.

However, on the same tablet models running Windows 11, the result of this command is:

```
Failed to access the interface: error 0x32.
```

Every device running windows 11 results in the same error.

Is there a reason why this command doesn't work on Windows 11? Or perhaps a setting I missed that needs to be enabled/disabled for it to work?

Is there an alternate way for me to get the ICC Id via command line?

LTE driver reinstalled twice, Cellular option most definitely enabled, SIM card definitely present & functional and all of the details I'm looking for can be found normally in Settings > Network & Internet > Mobile > Operator Settings > Properties; it just won't show with the same command on Win11 as it does on Win10

End goal is to be able to fetch the ICC Id from within a C# application, which is why it needs to be command line and not through Windows GUI.

Comment: Try `netsh mbn show readyinfo *`.

Comment: @harrymc this also results in "Failed to access the interface: error 0x32.". Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Error 0x32 is hard to find, but may mean that the interface is disabled. Could you please add the results of `netsh mbn show read interface = *` to your post? Have you run the commands as Admin?

Comment: `netsh mbn show read interface = * ` is what I already use on the Windows 10 version and it works perfectly, just not in Windows 11. The result of this same command on Windows 11 is the one with error 0x32 as I said. I have run the command both in user context and as admin, same result - though the command will need to run in user context in the end. The interface is not disabled, the tablet has a functioning APN and connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't think of this before, but I seem to be able to get just what I need from the Registry. I used the "Find" function in the registry editor and searched for the SIM ICC which I got from the Windows GUI. After a few potential keys, I arrived at one that seems to list only the currently present SIM card's ICC Id.

In `Computer\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Multivariant\UI\Candidates\UICC\` there is a singular subkey named after the SIM ICC. I can read the Candidates key and fetch the subkeys which returns the name of the 1 subkey present and it is the SIM ICC. If I swap out the SIM for another and run the same function, I get the new SIM card's ICC and no other subkeys, showing that the old entry is removed / renamed.

Tested now on Win10 and Win11 tablets and works on both.

I would be very interested to find out why the `NETSH` command returns an error though.